# How to disable the shared folder option in capistrano-node-deploy

Tags: node.js, npm, capistrano

If you have non-release directories in your release folder, the npm install command will fail like the following,

```
  * executing `node:install_packages'
  * executing "ls -x /home/ubuntu/support/releases"
    servers: ["spp"]
    [spp] executing command
    command finished in 296ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/support/releases/surveys.csv/node_modules ; cp -r /home/ubuntu/support/releases/surveys.csv/node_modules /home/ubuntu/support/releases/20150203163509"
    servers: ["spp"]
    [spp] executing command
 ** [out :: spp] mkdir:
 ** [out :: spp] cannot create directory `/home/ubuntu/support/releases/surveys.csv'
 ** [out :: spp] : Not a directory
 ** [out :: spp] 
 ** [out :: spp] cp:
 ** [out :: spp] cannot stat `/home/ubuntu/support/releases/surveys.csv/node_modules'
 ** [out :: spp] : Not a directory
 ** [out :: spp] 
    command finished in 307ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

Here's what the releases directory looks like...

```
> ls -lt
total 66324
drwxrwsr-x 13 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Feb  3 05:58 20150109231012
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   672733 Feb  1 10:01 surveys.csv
drwxrwsr-x 13 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Dec 10 19:15 20141210191517
```

The project considers this a feature, but I'd rather not try to share/copy old node_modules directories when deploying a new version.

Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

It failed because the `surveys.csv` file is newer than the `previous_release` dir, it should work if you deploy again.

You can override the `node:install_packages` task:

```
Rake::Task["node:install_packages"].clear_actions
namespace :node do
  task :install_packages do
    run "cd #{release_path} && npm install --loglevel warn"
  end
end
```